# Show $\mathcal S$ is a sigma Algebra

Tags: measure-theory

Let $X\neq \emptyset$ and $\mathcal S \subseteq \mathcal P(X)$ with the following properties:
a) $\emptyset \in \mathcal S$
b) $A,B \in \mathcal S\Rightarrow A\cup B \in \mathcal S$
c) $A\in \mathcal S \Rightarrow A^c \in \mathcal S$
d) If $A_n$ is a sequence with $A_n\subseteq A_{n+1} \forall n\in \mathbb N$, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in \mathcal S$.
Show that $\mathcal S$ is a sigma-Algebra
I only have to prove that for every sequence $B_n\in \mathcal S$, i have $\bigcup B_n\in \mathcal S$ .
I dont know how to show this property. Thanks for help.

Comment: Take $A_n=B_1\cup B_2\cup...\cup B_n$.

Comment: @geetha290krm So $A_n=\bigcup_{k=1}^n B_k$. So now I have to show that $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n\in \mathcal S$, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What Geetha290krm's comment wants to say is :-

Take any countable collection of sets $\{B_{n}\}$ .

Then $A_{n}=\bigcup_{i=1}^{n}B_{i}$ is a sequence of sets such that $A_{n}\subseteq A_{n+1}$

Hence by assumption $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}\in S$ .

But $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_{n}=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}$ and hence $\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}B_{n}\in S$